# Access denied when trying to add front end to server farm. Why?

Tags: front-end, access-denied, server-farm, configuration-wizard

I'm trying to add another front end server to my wss server farm. For some reason, the 'SP product and technologies configuration wizard' is failing at step 2 - throwing an access denied error.

In my setup I have a web server which hosts the central admin site and a single sp application. I also have a database server which hosts the sp databases.

I'm trying to join database server as another front end so I can integrate ssrs with sharepoint.

I've reset the farm account's password (to be sure it's correct) and have made sure that it has db_owner rights to the wss config database. I'm a little confused about all the moving parts regarding user accounts, which is makes this difficult, but I *think* things are setup correctly. Regardless, I'm having this issue.

Anyone have any steps to help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you may also need to add the dbcreator and securityadmin server roles to your user in SQL Server.  Have you looked at the SharePoint logs (in the "12 hive") and the Windows Event Viewer on both servers already?  They are helpful in diagnosing configuration issues.

Comment: Got a similar problem here now. Maybe it's related? http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/7409/why-401-unauthorized-when-configuring-ssrs-in-integration-mode